# Is there a way to modify a running countdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently creating a game for a game jam organized by my school, using html, css, javascript and jQuery.

In this game, i'm using a countdown (which works fine), but i'd like it to lose 2 seconds when my character is getting hit by enemies. When the countdown reaches 0, the player loses the game.

To do so, I'm using the "jChavannes"' github ([Link here](https://github.com/jchavannes/jquery-timer)) that is really complete, but I can't find a way to modify the countdown while it's running even though 'jchavannes' put a lot of tools to use his work.

Here is the HTML code of what i'd like to make work, with buttons of what I need to modify the countdown and the javascript of what I'm using to make the whole thing work (one library is missing but it's way too big to be put here, you'll find it in the Github).

Is there a simply way to modify the remaining time, or is it simply not designed to be modified without stopping and resetting it?

```js
var Example2 = new (function() {
    var $countdown,
        $form, // Form used to change the countdown time
        incrementTime = 70,
        currentTime = 30000,
        updateTimer = function() {
            $countdown.html(formatTime(currentTime));
            if (currentTime == 0) {
                Example2.Timer.stop();
                timerComplete();
                Example2.resetCountdown();
                return;
            }
            currentTime -= incrementTime / 10;
            if (currentTime < 0) currentTime = 0;
        },
        timerComplete = function() {
            alert('Example 2: Countdown timer complete!');
        },
        init = function() {
            $countdown = $('#countdown');
            Example2.Timer = $.timer(updateTimer, incrementTime, true);
            $form = $('#example2form');
            $form.bind('submit', function() {
                Example2.resetCountdown();
                return false;
            });
        };
    this.resetCountdown = function() {
        var newTime = parseInt($form.find('input[type=text]').val()) * 100;
        if (newTime > 0) {currentTime = newTime;}
        this.Timer.stop().once();
    };
    $(init);
});
//I tried to trigger some commands, in vain
$("#timerOnce5000").click(function(){
console.log("euh ouais ?");
$("#countdown").timer.once(5000);
});
$("#timerSetTime1000").click(function(){
    console.log("allô ?");
    $("#countdown").timer.set({time:1000});
});
$("#timerSetTime5000").click(function(){
    console.log("bonjour ?");
    $("#countdown").timer.set({time:5000});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en"> 
    <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="Jason Chavannes" />
    <title>jQuery Timer Demo</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="res/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="res/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.timer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="res/demo.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <body>
    <h3>Example 2 - Countdown Timer</h3>
    <span id="countdown">05:00:00</span>
    <form id="example2form">
        <input type='button' value='Play/Pause' onclick='Example2.Timer.toggle();' />
        <input type='button' value='Stop/Reset' onclick='Example2.resetCountdown();' />
        <input type='text' name='startTime' value='300' style='width:30px;' />
    </form>

    <div class='example-four'>
        <input type='button' value='timer.reset()' onclick='timer.reset();' /><br/>
        <input type='button' value='timer.once()' onclick='timer.once();' /><br/>
        <input type='button' value='timer.once(5000)' id="timerOnce5000" onclick='timer.once(5000);' /><br/>
        <input type='button' value='timer.set({time:1000})' id ="timerSetTime1000" onclick='timer.set({time:1000});' /><br/>
        <input type='button' value='timer.set({time:5000})' id="timerSetTime5000" onclick='timer.set({time:5000});' />
    </div>
    <br/>
```

Comment: Move `currentTime` onto `this` instead of `var`, or provide some method which modifies `currentTime`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you simulating a 'hit by enemy', in this case try:

```
var Example2 = new (function() {
...

...
  this.hitByEnemy() = function {
    currentTime = currentTime - 2000; //assuming milliseconds is units
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class='example-four'>
   ...
   <input type='button' value='hit by enemy' onclick='Example2.hitByEnemy();' /><br/>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't think about using this.hitbyenemy INSIDE the Example2 function, and I tried it, it WORKS ! Thank you so much !!

Answer (score 2):

One of the cool things about Javascript (even if it can be a little dangerous at times) is that it's generally pretty easy to modify a shared variable/resource to influence the behavior of other parts of your code. Some people don't like this because it can make things hard to debug if you make your functions too intertwined. I personally think it can be really useful in limited scenarios like yours.

So  my approach would be just to have a function that modifies `currentTime` when your player gets hit. Something like:

```
var $countdown,
    $form,
    // ... the other stuff you had in your provided code
    hitHandler = function() { // you'll need to call this when your player gets hit
      currentTime -= 2 * incrementTime;
      if (currentTime < 0) currentTime = 0;
    }
```

That said, you could also add a new variable that records hits and you can use that when you update the timer on your regular interval. This would be the "cleaner" solution, but it's also a little verbose, and might not be what you want if you don't want to wait for the increment function before decrementing your timer. That said, it'd look like:

```
  var $countdown,
      $form,
      // ...
      hits = 0
      hitHandler = function() {
        hits++;
      }
      updateTimer = function() {
        $countdown.html(formatTime(currentTime));
        if (currentTime == 0) {
            Example2.Timer.stop();
            timerComplete();
            Example2.resetCountdown();
            return;
        }
        currentTime -= incrementTime / 10;
        currentTime -= hits * (2 * incrementTime);
        hits = 0;
        if (currentTime < 0) currentTime = 0;
      }
```